# unique download link created after button link on website (not sure what language to search on internet)

Tags: button, hyperlink, download, click, unique

I would like to learn what language the following is done in
:

1. user comes to site and fills out mailing list form (for example)
2. when user submits the form, a unique download link is generated for the file( for example:  www.myDomain.com/downloads/myFile.zip)
3. Bonus: have that link expire after 24 hours or however long seems necessary (I actually believe that is done with PHP, which I have been playing with, but am not even a novice yet)

I am not looking for anyone to give me the answer, but maybe point me in the right direction as to where to learn.  I have googled many different variations of "unique download link on button click".

My level of knowledge is XHTML/CSS, and I have played with JavaScript and PHP, but as I said, I am not even a novice.  I am looking more for what language this is done in so I can work towards it.

Comment: Nobody can answer this: 'to learn what language the following is done in'

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in pretty much any server side language including PHP. How it works is the user submits the HTML form and a PHP script will process it to see if it's filled in correctly and matches all the criteria (emails are actual emails, names aren't blank etc.). Then it would use a database backend to insert the details of the form so you have it for your records.

For the download link, once you enter the form details, it would generate a token link just for that user which has a timestamp, both (Token and Timestamp) of which will be stored in your database. This link point to your PHP script which will take in the token (URL GET Variable) and check if the token is valid and if the file timestamp is less than 24 hours. If both these conditions are true, it'll serve the file to the user for download otherwise it'll show an error.

PHP and MySQL would be a good enough tool and should be fairly easy to get started with the documentation around.

Steps:

1. Look into how to capture form input in PHP (validations and security too)
2. Storing the input in a Database (MySQL for example)
3. Generating a token link and store in Database with timestamp and serve to user
4. When token link is accessed, checking if token is valid and timestamp is not more than 24 hours

Comment: Suhail, thank you so much.  I appreciate the explanation and the steps.  I will start my research.